# How to impersonate a user in Strapi when using API tokens?

Tags: rest, authentication, authorization, strapi, impersonation

I am calling Strapi v4 REST API endpoints authenticated via an API token.

My problem is that any resource created this way has its **created by** field empty. Is it possible to use an API token to impersonate an actual admin user, so that resources will have proper ownership?

I am looking for either a plugin or a code solution. I also have control over the API calls so I can pass any needed headers.

Comment: There is only way to use `extensions` here. `createdBy` field is only populated by admin user so unless you are authenticated with admin token you likely not going to fill it…

Comment: As a suggestion you could pass `createdBy: someId` along with your data

Comment: @antokhio I ended up using a custom field.